# Casting and instance of or nearly empty interface?

Tags: java, interface, instanceof

I'm programming some kind of board game containing robots, items and such.

At one point, I need to get the energy value of a robot or an item that can have energy. The way this is programmed is that each robot and each item having energy have an EnergyContainer class as a field (to prevent code redundancy) and an energy Value class.

Now, basically, I call a method evaluate() that receives an Element. Element is an abstract class which robot and items extend. Not all elements have energycontainers. If possible, I need to call the getEnergyContainer on this element, but only if it is an element that has it of course.

I can think of a couple  solutions: using a lot of instanceOf and then casting. So asking for example, if the element is instanceof robot, cast element to robot and call  getEnergyContainer on the element. This has as clear disadvantage that I need to do this for every energy having subclass of element.

Second solution is defining an interface containing only a getEnergyContainer method and make all energy having classes implement this. The only purpose for this interface is then to facilitate the one method and it would be nearly empty.

Unless anybody has a better idea, what is the "best" solution? Nearly empty interfaces are used as Marker interfaces I think, but this it is one and only purpose so I'm a bit inclined against it.

Comment: it would be a lot useful if you would post atleast the generic structure of your code.

Comment: Sorry, due to various reasons I'd prefer not to do that. Sorry for the inconvenience this causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If possible, I need to call the getEnergyContainer on this element, but only if it is an element that has it of course.

Why would you not want to call it on an element that doesn't have an energy container? If it *doesn't* have an energy container, either return a reference to some "null object" implementation of `EnergyContainer`, or return a null reference. It depends on what you want to do with it later - if you can easily implement some sort of "neutral" energy container, then the null object pattern is the simplest approach. Otherwise, just:

```
EnergyContainer container = element.getEnergyContainer();
if (container != null) {
    // Use the container
}
```

There are no doubt those who would argue that this is in some senses "impure" - but it's almost certainly *simpler* than most alternatives.

Comment: In the "impure" league (!), I'd say that it's a bit like: `Animal fish = new Fish(); Leg leg = fish.getLeftLeg(); if (leg == null) etc.`... Not sure I like it very much.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is simpler, but I think I'll agree with assylias here that I don't like it very much as a solution. I personally prefer some extra code then slightly "impure" code. Sorry, but still thanks!

Comment: @assylias: I wouldn't want to do it *much*, but I do like the simplicity of it. Effectively, an energy container is an optional part of an element, by the sounds of it. Alternatives like having a separate interface are going to add complexity without making anything materially cleaner, IMO. What's your better alternative?

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand your point - I would probably go for an `EnergyElement` class/interface, subclass/interface of Element and super class/interface of Robot, with the required method, but according to the OP it is not an option. So your solution could be a good compromise in that context.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to put the `getEnergyContainer()` method in one of the super classes of all energy containing elements the overriding this method in each elements class. You can make this method `abstract` to ensure its over-ridden. your super-class for this could be `Element` because you said: `Element is an abstract class which robot and items extend.`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This isn't possible since there are multiple super classes but none that includes all the energy having elements. It requires the creation of an interface to do that, so I'll guess this is a vote for that.

Comment: @Sven: well in that case you would have to do with creating an interface for two reasons: 1) it will be more readable and maintainable and 2) the overhead is slightly less than multiple uses of instanceof and also coz instanceof could be problematic if the energy elements extend each other.

Answer (score 0):

Given your class hierarchy use composition with an Interface to provide default EnergyContainer behaviour

```
abstract class Element {

    EnergyContainer ec = new EmptyEnergyContainer();

    int getEnergyValue() {
        getEnergyContainer().getValue();
    }

    EnergyContainer getEnergyContainer() {
        return ec;
    }

    setEnergyContainer(EnergyContainer container) {
        this.ec = container;
    }
}

class Robot extends Element {

    public Robot() {
        this.ec = new ActiveEnergyContainer();
    }
}

class Item extends Element{

    public Item() {
        this.ec = new ActiveEnergyContainer();
    }
}

class Brick extends Element{
    // will have a EmptyEnergyContainer by default
}
```

The Interface hierarchy for the EnergyContainer is like this

```
interface EnergyContainer {
    int getValue();
    setValue(int value);
}

class EmptyEnergyContainer implements EnergyContainer {
    @Override
    int getValue() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    setValue(int val) {
        throw Exception("Can not charge an empty container");
    }
}

class ActiveEnergyContainer implements EnergyContainer {
    int value;

    @Override
    int getValue() {
        return 17 + 3;  // calculate the value
    }

    @Override
    setValue(int val) {
        this.value = val // or do some funky calculation
    }
}
```

At runtime you are able to set new EnergyContainer types for your objects. If you have multiple parent classes like `Element` then you will have to follow the same pattern of adding the default behaviour to the abstract parent and override as required.

Having the default behaviour return a sensible default value for getValue() will help you not have to use `instanceof` all over the place.

Potential improvements to this code would be to introduce

1. AbstractFactory pattern for creating the various EnergyContainer
   variants
2. Including a `hasEnergy()` method to make your code more readable rather than checking for a value == 0
3. Make `Element` implement an Interface if other similar parent classes will include simlar methods